# Error not displaying Status column in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of Javascript like this:

```
$.each(dat, function (i, item) {
                    html += '<tr>';
                        html += '<td>' + item.ID + '</td>';
                        html += '<td>' + item.Name + '</td>';
                        html += '<td> <input data-id="' + item.ID + '" class="form-control" type="number" value="' + item.Salary + '" /> </td>';
                        html += '<td>' + item.Status == true ? 'Active' : 'Locked' + '</td>';
                        html += '<td>';
                            html += '<button class="btnEdit btn btn-warning" data-id="' + item.ID + '">Edit</button>';
                            html += '<button class="btn btn-danger btn_Delete" data-id="' + item.ID + '">Delete</button>';
                        html += '</td>';
                    html += '</tr >';
                });
```

But it does not show the Status column when running. I was wrong somewhere. help.

```
 html += '<td>' + item.Status == true ? 'Active' : 'Locked' + '</td>';
```

Comment: 1. Do you initialize `html = ""` ? 2. Your ternary is read as :  `html += ( '<td>' + item.Status == true ) ? 'Active' : ( 'Locked' + '</td>' )` which is probably not what you want.

Comment: People who downvote: Please explain in a comment why this question is not good, so that the OP can improve it and write better questions in the future.

Comment: It does not work

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put your ternary inside ( ).
Try this:

```
html += '<td>' + (item.Status == true ? 'Active' : 'Locked') + '</td>';
```

A little note, when checking if something is true you could just do this:

```
html += '<td>' + (item.Status ? 'Active' : 'Locked') + '</td>';
```